# Deriving power formulas for transmission lines

Tags: power, transmission-line, power-engineering, transmission, formula-derivation

I'm trying to derive formulas for active power (\$P_s\$) and reactive power (\$Q_s\$) at the sending end of a transmission line shown below:
[image]

Where:
\$E_s\$ and \$E_r\$ are voltage magnitudes

\$X\$ is the unit line reactance

\$\alpha\$ and \$0°\$ are the load angles

I think the equations are these, but I'm unsure of how to take into account the reactance values.

Would line 2 and 3 be in parallel then in series with the rest?

And would the load angle be the sum of those shown in the diagram (in this case \$\alpha+0°\$)?

$$ S_r = P_r + jQ_r = E_r\dot{I^*}$$

$$ = E_r\left[\frac{E_scos\delta+jE_ssin\delta-E_r}{jX}\right]$$

$$ = \frac{E_sE_r}{X}sin\delta + j\frac{E_sE_rcos\delta-E_r^2}{X}$$

$$\boxed{ P_r = P_s = \frac{E_sE_r}{X}sin\delta  \\
 Q_r = \frac{E_sE_rcos\delta-E_r^2}{X} \\
 Q_s = \frac{E_s^2-E_sE_rcos\delta}{X}               }$$

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers that express results in terms of the voltage at the source and load are answers that will earn however many mercy points are awarded for the good math enthusiastically applied without understanding the course material.  (One out of 10)

A zero voltage angle in a power systems course isn’t a reference phase it’s relative to the current. That meant that the load presented to the source had to be a real impedance a finite non-zero resistance and zero reactance.

Begin an answer by declaring that a problem with two indefinite normalizing impedances Zs=Es/Is and X would have one too many so you take the description of X as the unit reactance literally.

I assume that you knew that two j3 in parallel is one 3/2j and then adding a 1j and a 1/2j in series brought the impedance of the series network full circle to 3j.

Your instructor denotes Voltage as EMF and uses E instead of V. Its not wrong, but I’ll be using Vs and Vl, not Es and El.

Given Vs is at angle zero, Zs is real, Rs = Vs/Is and Xs=0,

The reactance of the network attached to the source which is also zero = Xx + Xl = 0, given that Xx = +3j,  Xl = -3j

Real power is the same at source and load given that the intervening network is dissipation-less.

Ps = Real(Pl) = Vs*Is

All that remains is to use a, the voltage angle at the load, to find the load impedance.

Zx and Zl are a voltage divider, Vl = Vs ( Zl / (Zs + Zl) )

The angle a is atan(imag(Vl)/real(Vl))

Vl = Vs * Zl/(Zx+Zl) = Vs ( Rl-j3/(Rs+j3 + Rl-j3)) = Vs ( Rl-j3/(Rs+Rl) )

The real part is Rl/(Rs + Rl), the imaginary part is -j3/(Rs + Rl)
The imaginary part divided by the real part is -3/(Rs+Rl), and a = atan(-3/(Rs+Rl)) so tan(a) = -3/(Rs + Rl) , and  Rl = -3/tan(a) - Rs  NB: to be realizable Rl must be >0 restricting the domain of angle a.

The insight the problem is expected to impart is that a neutralized series/parallel reactance has the functional effect of inserting a transformer between a real source and a real load. Reactive impedance matching is topic that was more relevant to RF and power systems engineering 50y ago. For power systems in the 21st century the important thing to absorb is that using a series reactance to neutralize load reactance changes the voltage across the real part if the load. Dynamically correcting a varying load power factor that’s far from unity by using switched a reactance bank tends to force also tap switching the distribution transformers to say within +/- 15% of nominal. If your power blinks for a half cycle a few times a day at roughly the same times each day, now you know why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, combine all of the reactances into a single equivalent value between the sources.

The load angle you show in your pasted equations (\$\delta\$) is the angle by which the sending end voltage leads the receiving end voltage.  In your one-line drawing, this is \$-\alpha\$.

It seems to me the easiest way to derive the power transfer equation is to let the receiving end bus be the reference at \$0^°\$ and your sending end have the phase angle.

Below I use \$\theta\$ for the phase angle and \$V\$ for receiving end voltage.

[image]

You know,

$$ \overline{I}=\frac{Ee^{j\theta}-V}{jX}$$

and you know,

$$ \overline{S}=Ee^{j\theta}\text{    }{\overline{I}}^* $$

So, you just simplify the above equation using Euler's \$e^{j\theta}=cos\theta+jsin\theta\$, collect terms, and you have it.